# Continuity of maximum function closed set

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.

a. Show that $A=\{x\in{X}|f(x)\geq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

b. Let $h:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function given by $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$. Show that $h$ is continuous.

For a, is it enough to say that $X\setminus A=\{x\in X|f(x)<g(x)\}$ is an open ball?

For b, I know that for any closed set $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $h$ will be continuous if $h^{-1}(C)\subseteq X$ is closed, but how do I go about showing this?

Comment: What's an open ball on a topological space?

Comment: Your sentence about (b) is incorrect. $h$ will be continuous if $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed for *any* closed $C\subset \Bbb R$. As you have written it, it seems that the continuty of $h$ depends on the choice of the closed set $C$.

Comment: Your thinking in b is wrong.  C is not in R, C is a subset of R.  Make the appropiate corrections.

Comment: Show b. by noting that $h = \dfrac{f+g}{2} + \dfrac{|f-g|}{2}$ and that the sum, difference and absolute value of continuous functions is continuous

Comment: @AryamanJal . I had forgotten that nice little move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a)$ we have that:

> $$A^c=\{x:g(x)>f(x)\}=\bigcup_{q \in \Bbb{Q}}\{x:g(x)>q>f(x)\}=\bigcup_{q \in \Bbb{Q}}(\{x:g(x)>q\} \cap \{x:f(x)<q\})$$

which is open as a union of open sets,which are intersections of inverse images of open unbounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ under continuous functions.

I leave to you as an exercise to prove the above set equalities.

Note that $$\{x:g(x)>q\}=g^{-1}(q,+\infty)$$ $$\{x:f(x)<q\}=f^{-1}(-\infty,q)$$

are open as inverse images of open sets.

We proved that the complement of $A$ is open thus $A$ is closed.

Comment: Why is $q\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @mrose ...I used the density of the rational numbers.

Comment: Would it still be true if $q\in\mathbb{R}$, or does the union have to be countable?

Comment: @mrose.. if you use density of irrationals it is true because an uncountable union of open sets is open .

Answer (score 1):

$h = f - g$ is continuous.

$A = h^{-1}([0,\infty))$ which is closed.

Comment: To the proposer:  To show continuity of $h$ it suffices that $h^{-1}(-\infty,a)$ and $h^{-1}(b,\infty)$ are open in $X$ for all $a,b\in \Bbb R.$ We have $h^{-1}(-\infty,a)=$ $\cup_{x\in \Bbb R}[\;(f^{-1}(-\infty,x)\cap (g^{-1}(x-a,\infty)\;].$

Answer (score 0):

d:X -> XxX, x -> (x,x) is continuous.

k:XxX -> RxR, (x,y) -> (f(x),g(y)) is contunuous.

max:RxR -> R, (x,y) -> max{x.y} is continuous.

h is a composition of continuous functions.